# F# TextEditor control for web

Tags: angularjs, f#, web-controls

I'm looking for a control I could integrate to my angular web application to let my users edit some F# code.

For now they just modify it through a regular text area.  The F# code is then saved in a database field and is compiled and executed by another external process.

But I'm looking for something providing keywords formatting and maybe intellisense.

There is no need to run the F# code, just a nice editor.

Thanks

Dan

Comment: take a look at here https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2015/03/06/digging-advanced-angularjs-directives/

Comment: Ace is de facto standard for web code editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two open source projects you can use:

- [FSharpWebIntellisense](https://github.com/BayardRock/FSharpWebIntellisense) provides an integration for the Ace editor and for CodeMirror. It is an older project that has been the core for the F# support for IPython Notebook and I also used it in a couple of project including [fun3d.net](http://www.fun3d.net). For Fun3D, I modified it a bit (made it simpler with Suave backend), so you might want to [use this version instead](https://github.com/tpetricek/Fun3D). I tried turning this into a [stand-alone repo](https://github.com/tpetricek/fsharp-web-editors) which can be referenced via Paket as [shown in a demo](https://github.com/tpetricek/fsharp-web-editors-demo).
- [Ionide Web](https://github.com/ionide/ionide-web) is a new work-in-progress project that brings Ionide (F# support for VS Code) to the web. This is based on the Monaco editor (by Microsoft) which is powering VS Code. I expect there will be more activity here in the near future.